# How can I solve the below Python question

Tags: python-3.x

> Evenly Divisible:
>
> Create a function that gets three arguments x,y,z as input and return the number of values in the range between x and y(both x and y are included) and evenly divisible by z.
>
> Sample case:-
> Sample Input 1 20 2 Sample Output 10
>
> Explanation:
>
> From the limit 1 to 20 the values 2,4,6,810,1214,16,18,20 are evenly divisible by 2,so the total number is evenly divisible by 10.

Comment: What do you mean by total number? Is it the sum of all the numbers in the range? or is it the sum of all the numbers that are evenly divisible by `z`? or it is the value of `y` which is 20 in this case? What is total number here?

Comment: Why I have an impression that you want us to do your homework? Or at least try to write the function on your own and then ask for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand it, you might use list comprehension as well.

```
def evendiv(x,y,z):
    return(len([i for i in range(x, y+1) if i%z==0]))

print(evendiv(2,26,4))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what your question is trying to say, but here is a function to find all numbers between `x` and `y` that are divisible by `z`.

```
def divisible_in_range(x, y, z):
    if x > y:
        x, y = y, x
    for i in range(x, y + 1):
        if i % z == 0:
            print(i)

# Call it with 3 values
```

This prints all the numbers, like so (inputs 1, 20, 10)

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

If this isn't what you expected, include more detail about what your function should do in the question.

I would recommend trying out some code before posting a question, as all this code requires is knowing what a function is and knowing the syntax for a for loop.

**EDIT**
Looking at your comment, you could do this:

```
def divisible_in_range(x, y, z):
    if x > y:
        x, y = y, x
    count = 0
    for i in range(x, y + 1):
        if i % z == 0:
            print(i)
            count += 1
    return count
```

And call it like this:

```
print(f"The number of numbers between 1 and 20 divisible by 2 is: {divisible_in_range(1, 20, 2)}")
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
The number of numbers between 1 and 20 divisible by 2 is: 10
```

Comment: It will return the value in range between x and y.

Comment: For example the three arguments of x, y and z is 2, 26 and 4. Now the values between x and y (i.e.  2 and 26) which is divisible by z(4) is 4,8,2,16,20 and 24. the outcome will be 6. So total of six values are divisible by 4. The code outcome will be 6. If the explanation helps you.